# Python: Dataframes to DB

Tags: python, sqlite, pandas

I have the following dictionary of dataframes created from a folder of excel files:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

files = glob.glob(os.path.join("staging" + "/*.csv"))

print(files)

# Create an empty dictionary to hold the dataframes from csvs
dict_ = {}

# Write the files into the dictionary
for file in files:
    dict_[file] = pd.read_csv(file, header = 0, dtype = str, encoding = 'cp1252').fillna('')

"""
Rewrite the dataframes to csv in utf8, overwriting old values 

for file in dict_:
    dict_[file].to_csv(file, encoding = 'utf-8')
"""
```

How can I now convert each dataframe into a seperate table in an sqlite database? I tried to use the following:

```
for file in files:
    pd.DataFrame(dict_[file].to_sql(file, conn, flavor = None,
                schema = None, if_exists = 'replace',index = True,
                index_label = None, chunksize = None, dtype = None))
```

However this code generates an error: Too many values to unpack
Would it be better to rewrite the CSVs in UTF-8 and use those files to build the DB?

Comment: You shouldn't be wrapping your `dict_[file].to_sql(...)` call as a `pd.DataFrame`

Comment: @asongtoruin what do you mean? how do i re-write it then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `dict_` already contains the DataFrames, you need to iterate over your dict_ values:

```
for df in dict_.values():
    df.to_sql(...)
```

If you want to use the key as the table's name, you can try something like:

`for key, df in dict_.items(): df.to_sql(key, conn, flavor = None, schema = None, if_exists = 'replace', index = True, index_label = None, chunksize = None, dtype = None)`

Also, the first argument of the `to_sql` method should be the name of the table where you want to insert your data. It should be a `str`. I don't think that is what you have right now. The `con` argument should be an `SQLAlchemy` or `pyscopg2` (or others) connexion to your database.

Take a look at the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html).

Comment: what is the name convention for the dict_.values(): statement? ie- what goes HERE  'code' pd.DataFrame(dict_[file].to_sql(HERE, conn, flavor = None,
                schema = None, if_exists = 'replace',index = True,
                index_label = None, chunksize = None, dtype = None)) 'code'

Comment: Your suggestion produces the following error: "DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type."

Comment: The `name` argument of the to_sql method should be a `str` representing the name of the table where you want to insert your data. I edited my response, take a look at it.

Comment: The issue is that for each df, the name should be the same as the csv filename, which is the way the dictionary is formatted. How do I transfer this logic to the import statement?

Comment: conn is the name of the variable for the connection to the database, which is defined in code that I omitted from my question

Comment: Then just use the key of the dictionary! The key of the dictionary is the name of the file, and the value is the dataframe! Try `for key, df in dict_.items(): df.to_sql(key, conn, flavor = None, schema = None, if_exists = 'replace', index = True, index_label = None, chunksize = None, dtype = None)`

Comment: Thank you! @Diego Mora Cespedes....one last question, how do i remove "staging/" from the table names?

Comment: @zsad512 `files = list(map(lambda x: x.split('staging/')[1], files))`

Comment: @zsad512 You can also do `files = [file.split('staging/')[1] for file in files]`