# Pandas DF columns to SQLite tables

Tags: python, sqlite, csv

I have a database that I have created in sqlite that was created from a dictionary of pandas dataframes that were created from a file of csv's. When I import the database to sqlite, each of the table names ends in ".csv" How can I strip this?

Here is the code:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

files = glob.glob(os.path.join("staging" + "/*.csv"))

print(files)

# Create an empty dictionary to hold the dataframes from csvs
dict_ = {}

# Write the files into the dictionary
for file in files:
    fname = os.path.basename(file)
    dict_[fname] = pd.read_csv(file, header = 0, dtype = str, encoding = 'cp1252').fillna('')
```

And for the sqlite DB:

```
# Create the SQL Lite database
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("medicare_hospital_compare.db")

# Convert the dict_[file]'s to SQL tables
for key, df in dict_.items(): 
    df.to_sql(key, conn, flavor = None, schema = None, if_exists = 'replace', 
              index = True, index_label = None, chunksize = None, dtype = None)
```

Comment: Simply: `file.replace('.csv', '')`

Comment: Also, per your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45105630/1422451) it seems like you are importing many tables of same structure which is not good database design. Import same structure into **one** table with a column indicator like *file*.

Comment: @Parfait- the tables do not have the same structure, they are all different. But your suggestion worked, thank you!